When navigating from a fragment containing a PreferenceScreen, artifacts appear in the Button
I have 2 Fragments, the second one contains the PreferenceScreen, the first one contains the RecyclerView, a root container for the RecyclerView - MaterialCard. The root container of the item is a MaterialCard, inside which there is a ConstraintLayout.
When navigating back from the settings screen, an artifact in the form of a rectangle appears in the buttons of the item list. After navigation, the button breaks and an artifact appears with every navigation action, even from other screens.
The artifact in the photo. 
I've tried changing foreground, background, and other attributes. I tried to change the tints, but unfortunately it does not give any results.
This behavior occurs on any buttons, which is for Material2``Button, which is for Material3 MaterialButton.
I will be very glad if someone can help with this.
